# ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync throwing DocumentClientException

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Trying to update the IndexingPolicy of a collection. The collection definition works fine when using CreateDocumentCollectionIsNotExistsAsync, but when trying to update the definition of an exising collection using ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync, a DocumentClientException is thrown. using .NET library 1.19.1. Exception details are:

```
DocDBTrace Error: 0 : DocumentClientException with status code NotFound, message: The value '' specified  for query '$resolveFor' is invalid., inner exception: null, and response headers: null
DocDBTrace Error: 0 : Operation will NOT be retried. Current attempt 0, Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.NotFoundException: The value '' specified  for query '$resolveFor' is invalid., documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.19.1 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentServiceRequest..ctor(OperationType operationType, ResourceType resourceType, String path, Stream body, AuthorizationTokenType authorizationTokenType, NameValueCollection headers)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentServiceRequest.Create(OperationType operationType, String relativePath, Resource resource, ResourceType resourceType, AuthorizationTokenType authorizationTokenType, NameValueCollection headers, SerializationFormattingPolicy formattingPolicy, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<ReplaceDocumentCollectionPrivateAsync>d__123.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__1b.MoveNext()
```

Updated with code. I'm trying to share the creation/modify index code, so I call CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistAsync first and if the collection exists, then I modify the index policy to match the latest.

```
    DocumentCollection appCollection = new DocumentCollection();
    appCollection.Id = CosmosDbCollectionName;

    // Set the index policy

     var rrdc = await cdbClient.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(CosmosDbDatabaseName), appCollection);
     if (true == rrdc.StatusCode.IsSuccessCode())
     {
       // If OK was returned, the collection already existed.
       if (HttpStatusCode.OK == rrdc.StatusCode)
       {
          var rr = await _cdbClient.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync(appCollection).ConfigureAwait(false);
          if (false == rr.StatusCode.IsSuccessCode())
               return false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: What does your call to the `DocumentClient.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync()` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the DocumentCollection resource instance returned from `CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync` to `ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync`.

For example:

```
DocumentCollection appCollectionSpec = new DocumentCollection();
appCollection.Id = CosmosDbCollectionName;

// Set the index policy

 ResourceResponse<DocumentCollection> rrdc = await cdbClient.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(CosmosDbDatabaseName), appCollectionSpec);
 if (true == rrdc.StatusCode.IsSuccessCode())
 {
   // If OK was returned, the collection already existed.
   if (HttpStatusCode.OK == rrdc.StatusCode)
   {
      var rr = await _cdbClient.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync(rrdc.Resource).ConfigureAwait(false);
      if (false == rr.StatusCode.IsSuccessCode())
           return false;
   }
}
```

I don't believe the DocumentCollection instance that is passed to `CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExists` is modified by the call, as it is treated as a 'spec' object. The replace operation requires internal metadata that is only populated by resources returned from the server.